# Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported in Wubi Ubuntu

Tags: dell, windows-10, wubi

Installed ubuntu along with Windows 10 using [Wubiuefi](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki).
After rebooting to Ubuntu, GRUB menu is loading with Error

```
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.
```

How can I load the Ubuntu and finish the set-up?

Comment: We don't support wubi here.

Comment: @Pilot6, What's the right place to get the help on this?

Comment: Ask on github. You can post issues there, first you can read existing.

Comment: Can you not select between Windows 10 and Ubuntu on the grub menu?

Comment: If you dual-boot with Windows, then that's the way it's configured to work... the GRUB menu allows you to select which OS to boot. Now... you CAN modify GRUB to default boot to Windows OR Ubuntu... or to not show the GRUB menu... and that involves editing /etc/default/grub. Which do you want to do?

Comment: Updated my question.